# cannot post $('#myid').val() via ajax post method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I cannot send the value of input type email via ajax post.i obtain the input value by

```
var email = $('#myid').val()
```

which is somemail@gmail.com.I can successfully alert this value but cannnot post the value.when i remove '@' from email,it successfully posts the value..
please check my code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function forgotfunction(){
    var email=$('#forgetpass').val();
    alert(email);
    $.post("forgetpass.php",
    {
      email:email
    },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      $('#modalLink').trigger("click");
    });

}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? The network tab to make sure the request and response look right? The value that the code on the server retrieves? At what point does it fail? What does "cannot post the value" mean?

Comment: look into post more.  I don't think you're doing it right: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: the value is not reaching server.(i checked by echo post value at server.),but when i give the var to post as string,it successfully posts.eg,instead of var email=$('#forgetpass').val() ,i give ar email="asas@gmail.com" ,it posts the email..

Comment: What does the request look like in the network tab of your browser's dev tools?

Comment: Do you have jQuery correctly linked in your header? As it stands, the code should work fine **[as seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/HLLM3/)**

Comment: What does `console.log(email);` give you exactly?

Comment: will the post data be url encoded,the network tab shows email asas@gmail.com is url encoded to asas%40gmail.com and shows status as cancelled..

Comment: @ WASasquatch,i told you the alert email,works but the email doesnot get posted untill i remove '@' or i send directly as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead this way:

```
function forgotfunction(){
    var email=$('#forgetpass').val();
    alert(email);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "forgetpass.php",
        data: { email: email },
        error: function(){ alert('Could not post email'); }
    });
    function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        $('#modalLink').trigger("click");
    });
}
```